# Proving almost sure finiteness of a stopping time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

Let $M_t$ be a local martingale and $S_t = \sup_{0 \leq s \leq t}M_s$  its running supremum. How can I show that the stopping time $T=\inf\{t \geq 0 : S_t - M_t = a\}$ for an arbitrary $a>0$ is almost surely finite given the fact that the quadratic variation of M almost surely diverges to infinity $(<M>_{\infty}=\infty)$ ?

Comment: Does the martingale have continuous sample paths?

Comment: @saz Yes, I make that implicit assumption. Otherwise, $T$ might not even be a stopping time.